# How to efficiently multiply rows in PySpark dataframe?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, union

I am trying to make a synthetic dataset by taking an existing small dataset and making it much larger. I want the target size to be 20M rows.
My current method:

```
for i in range(int(log(130000, 2))): 
    table_copy = table_copy.unionAll(table_copy)
```

But this slows down A LOT after the 12th iteration (of 17). Is there a much faster way of making the dataframe consisting of 150 rows into 20M?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This works best**:
(5 seconds = 20M rows)

```
df = spark.range(150)
factor = 135000
df = df.withColumn('a', F.expr(f'explode(array_repeat(0,{factor}))')).drop('a')
```

<sup>Idea proposed by [this smart guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2986344)</sup>

*In your case it could be just*:

```
table_copy = table_copy.withColumn('a', F.expr('explode(array_repeat(0,135000))')).drop('a')
```

---

**Other tested options**

(16 seconds = 1.5M rows)

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df = spark.range(150)
df = df.withColumn('array', F.explode(F.array(*map(F.lit, range(1000)))))
df = df.drop('array')
```

(11 seconds = 38k rows):

```
def union_self(df, p):
    if p:
        df = union_self(df, p - 1)
        return df.union(df)
    return df

df = spark.range(150)
df = union_self(df, 8)
```

(16 seconds = 38k rows):

```
from functools import reduce
df = spark.range(150)
df = reduce(lambda df1, df2: df1.union(df2), [df] * 256)
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this! Can you also help me understand why my original method takes so long compared to this one?

Comment: Apparently, splitting is just more effective than many many unions. I don't know the reason, but you can see that Spark creates completely different physical plans for both versions. You can see them by using `table_copy.explain()` after both versions.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right. you want *expand or scale-up* the dataset multiple with same data:

```scala
val replicas = 5 // calcu yourself and i've never try 20M
val dsReplicated = ds.flatMap(a => 0 until replicas map ((a, _))).map(_._1)
```

or for dataframe:

```scala
val dfReplicated = df
      .withColumn("__temporarily__", functions.typedLit((0 until replicas).toArray))
      .withColumn("idx", functions.explode($"__temporarily__"))
      .drop($"__temporarily__")
      .drop($"idx")
```